# NSAttributedString how to use NSParagraphStyle to set line of text center alignment

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to modify my attributed text in UILable to have one line centered. 
So I am adding attributes to NSAttributedString with NSParagrahStyle as below

```
var centerParagraphAttributes : [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] {

        let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraph.alignment = .center

        return [
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraph,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : AppFonts.SFUITextBold.font(size: 14.0)
        ]
    }

 // center - or -
            if let range = attributedText.string.range(of: "\n\r- or -\n\r") {
                let nsrange = NSRange(range, in: attributedText.string)
                attributedText.addAttributes(centerParagraphAttributes, range: nsrange)
            }
```

But this code doesn't do anything and line is left aligned as previously.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the above code works and aligns line of text. I only tried to set paragraph style on substring without `"\n\r"` special characters that start new paragraphs, and then after adding this to substring I've left empty space between `"\n\r - or -\n\r"` So it doesn't match `range(of: "\n\r- or -\n\r")`

More over it even works when using just leading "\n\r- or -" so no extra space at bottom of paragraph is needed